# Method returns value but "Control may reach end of non-void function"

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm new to obj-c, here writing a convenience routine to fetch entities from a Core Data store. XCode is warning me that I'm missing a return value. Why?

```
 - (NSArray *)findEntities:(NSString *)entityName byField:(NSString *)fieldName andValue:(id)fieldValue
 {
     NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:entityName];
     NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == %@", fieldName, fieldValue];
     [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
     NSError *error;
     NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
     if (error) {
         NSLog(@"LWStore: findEntities error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
     }
     return fetchedObjects;
 }
```

The warning is attached to the executeFetchRequest line.

Comment: Did you try clean and build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pasting this code into a new project gives me no errors, which is understandable since it looks like you'd always return a value. Try cleaning, analyzing or anything that will cause Xcode to check for errors anew and see if the error goes away.

Answer (score 0):

Do a clean and build. Press `command + shift + K` as the shortcut and then `command + b`. I am able to build your method without any warnings. It might be an earlier warning which was there on that line. A clean and build should fix it.